# Problem with changing resolution on Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, rdp

I use remmina to remotely connect to my Virtual Machine, Ubuntu (xenial xerus). When I changed the display resolution on it from 1680×1050 to 1280×1024 it froze and lost the connection. Then it showed me this attempt notification and tried to connect to it again. The thing is after it got connected it shows a totally different session. Initially I had some programs opened before I changed it, but the new session has nothing opened. Also, sometimes it loses connection from a new session, too, and shows me an old session where all my programs are opened, but I can't interact, then it disconnects again showing a new session, and it may go on endlessly…

[image]

I tried changing resolutions from remmina, but it didn't help. If any additional information is needed, please ask. I also tried changing resolution from that new session where initial resolution is 1680×1050, but after it disconnects and reconnects it the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out changing resolution messes up RDP connections. I greped all the connections via

```
ps -ef | grep vnc
```

and killed all the extra connections with different resolutions, which helped.